# Display different language text in <noscript> tag, depending on browser language

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML, and I want to display a message when JavaScript is disabled. So I put the message inside `<noscript>` tag, which works fine.

```html
<noscript> Need to enable Javascript. </noscript>
```

But I want to change this language to Chinese when the browser language is Chinese. I can't use JavaScript because this message only displays when JavaScript is disabled. Is there any way to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Since you can not draw advantage of DOM you need to use server side language as for example php https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-browser-language-in-php/

Comment: You need a way of doing something on the server-side. Tell us what server-side language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

When a browser makes an HTTP request, it sends an [`Accept-Language` request HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language).

So, for example if you are using PHP, you could use the following to get this header value:

```php
$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]
```

or

```php
$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"]
```

You can use this value to decide on the server-side which language is being used and insert the text in the correct language.

Comment: Could you explain when I could use which one ?

Comment: I can't use PHP since it is an HTML file, and I'm using React.

Comment: You can't use React, @Xu阿兮, if you can't use JavaScript, unless you're using React-Native or server-side React.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python in browser with Transcrypt

Download Python  from [www.python.org](http://www.python.org)
Install Transcrypt from the command prompt by typing python -m pip install transcrypt
Create a new folder hello containing hello.html and hello.py
Go to that new folder and type `python -m transcrypt -b -m -n hello.py`
In that same new folder start an HTTP server by typing python -m http.server
In your browser, navigate to localhost:8000/hello.html to see the result

```
print request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

Answer (score 0):

that's quite easy if I'm getting what you actually want and assuming that you dont change the HTML file, do as below

```
const userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; //1-this detects the browser language
//2-in my case i use en-US, change it to zh-sg or any other language iso for chinese
if(userLang === "en-US"){ 
//3-i used a nonScript class on <nonscript> tag to chnage the language
document.querySelector(".nonScript").textContent = "Change to chinese language";
}
```

you can use `alert(userLang);` to detect your browser language and use the iso u get for the if condition

Comment: How will this work if you have JavaScript disabled like the question is asked?